# Error in using GADEM function from rGADEM package

Tags: r, bioinformatics, genetics

I have big peak list in the "Bed" format and I converted it to GenomicRange for use as an input for the GADEM package to find denovo motifs. But when I try the GADEM function always I face the below error.

Could you please anybody who knows help me with this error?

- This is a small example of my real file with only 20 rows.

```
1      chr6  29723590  29723790
2     chr14 103334312 103334512
3      chr1 150579030 150579230
4      chr7  76358527  76358727
5      chr6  11537891  11538091
6     chr14  49893256  49893456
7      chr5 179623200 179623400
8      chr1 228082831 228083031
9     chr12  93441644  93441844
10    chr10   3784776   3784976
11     chr3 183635833 183636033
12     chr7    975301    975501
13    chr12 123364510 123364710
14     chr1   1615578   1615778
15     chr1  36156320  36156520
16    chr14  55051781  55051981
17     chr8  11867697  11867897
18    chr22  38706135  38706335
19     chr6  44265256  44265456
20     chr1 185316658 185316858
```

and the code that I use is :

```
library(GenomicRanges)
library(rGADEM)
data = makeGRangesFromDataFrame(data, keep.extra.columns = TRUE)
data = reduce(data)
data = resize(data, width = 50, fix='center')
gadem<-GADEM(data,verbose=1,genome=Hsapiens)
plot(gadem)
```

and error is:

**[ Retrieving sequences... Error in.Call2("C_solve_user_SEW", refwidths, start, end, width, translate.negative.coord:
solving row 136: 'allow.nonnarrowing' is FALSE and the supplied start (55134751) is > refwidth + 1 ]**

Better to mention that, when I try an example input file with less than 136 rows, it works and I get motifs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are on the right path by checking that file with less then 136 rows works. Try to check what exact coordinates are at row 136 and how long is the chromosome for which the range is defined.

Comment: @MarekSchwarz  Thanks for your response. You right but even when I remove that row, I still get same error in row 136. I think it could be s.th else than length of chromosome. I'm not sure...

Comment: @MarekSchwarz  sorry may I send the original file to you?

Comment: @MarekSchwarz  coordinate at row 136 is 55134751- 55135000 in chromosome 1. and i have coordinates based on hg19.